# How to accurately use the epi.kappa() function in R?

Tags: r, cohen-kappa

I am attempting to perform a kappa statistic test on 2 indices I created. I've found that there are multiple packages in R that have functions for this and am trying to compare two functions: the epi.kappa() function in the epiR package and the cohen.kappa() function from the psych package.

I was able to successfully use the cohen.kappa() function with my data however, I continue to get errors when using the epi.kappa() function. My code is as follows

```
library(epiR)
kap.dat = matrix(c(275,78,305,154),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(kap.dat) = c("I1-0","I1-1")
rownames(kap.dat) = c("I2-0","I2-1")
epi.kappa(kap.dat,method="cohen",alternative= "two.sided",conf.level=0.95)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in epi.kappa(kap.dat,method="cohen",alternative="two.sided", : 
  object `pO.p` not found
```

Comment: I can't replicate. Your code runs fine on my machine. Try restarting R?

Comment: hmm, that's really weird. what exactly do you get as the output? even after restarting and clearing the environment, I still get the same error.

Comment: I get a list with named members "prop.agree", "pabak", "kappa"  and  "z" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you've got the latest version of epiR installed and update if necessary. Latest version on CRAN is 2.0.50. Type `help(epi.about)` once package loaded --- version of package will be shown at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb. I was using an older version of the package and updating it to the latest solved this.